# rake aborted! no such file to load -- pg (Creating postgre database in rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, rake

I'm trying to start a rails project with a postgresql database but when i try to create the db with the command:

rake db:create

I'm getting the following error message:

rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pg

I'm using mac os X so postgresql is intalled in the /Library folder. I've look around for the pg file but i could not find it and i

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL 9 downloaded from [enterprisedb](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do) you need to install the pg gem in one of the following way:

If you use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) use:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" \
  gem install pg -- \
  --with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/include/ \
  --with-pg-lib=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/
```

Otherwise use:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" \
  gem install pg -- \
  --with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/include/ \
  --with-pg-lib=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/
```

If that doesn't work, we need to know which version of OSX and which version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I got the gem installed this way. But when I execute rake db:create I'm still getting the rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pg UPDATE: I miss to include it into Gemfile and the bundle install. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

make sure you have the pg gem installed.

`gem install pg`

or

include `gem pg` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`  if using bundler

Comment: i've tried to install it but when i'm doing it i get: Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

All right. Another day, another opportunities.

I found the problem! If you want to install "gem install pg" you need to have the postgres header files on your machine. After I installed Postgres 8.3 via Macports I was also able to install the pg gem. I used this command to install the pg gem:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386' gem install pg
```

I found the solution in this blog post:

http://flux88.com/blog/installing-postgresql-for-rails-on-mac-os-x/

After reading the post and all the comments, I could resolve the problem.

Comment: The accepted answer of the question exactly proposes the same solution

Answer (score 1):

For me it does not work.

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/local/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb --with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/ --with-pg-lib=/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/ --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Ruby + PostgreSQL = Pain in the ASS!

I not wondering why everybody uses mySQL instead of Postgres. With mySQL I never had so much trouble. It is easy to install and easy to use. With Postgres I have always just problems.

After hours of troubleshooting and googeling for shitty postgres ruby driver I am very pissed off. Tomorrow I will take a look to MongoDB and I hope it is less pain than Postgres!

good night!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't install PostgreSQL properly.

User Brew to install PostgreSQL.

```
brew update
```

then install PostgreSQL.

```
brew install postgresql
```

Make sure you follow the instructions for PostgreSQL and that the version you installed matches the version you are using.

you can get the version by doing.

```
psql --version
```

PostgreSQL is worth learning and much more advanced than MYSQL. Used properly it will improve your Rails application.

This tutorial helped me learn.

The problem is you didn't install PostgreSQL properly.

User Brew to install PostgreSQL.

```
brew update
```

then install PostgreSQL.

```
brew install postgresql
```

Make sure you follow the instructions for PostgreSQL and that the version you installed matches the version you are using.

you can get the version by doing.

```
psql --version
```

PostgreSQL is worth learning and much more advanced than MYSQL. Used properly it will improve your Rails application.

This tutorial helped me learn.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql